# Clarification for all Data Extensions' templates

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, template

I would like to clarify several Data Extensions templates since there is almost no documentation available.
To be exact, I would like to know what are the use-cases and implementation steps for those templates:

| Template | Comments |
| --- | --- |
| **AudienceBuilderResult** | no info. |
| **CONTEXTUAL_SUPPRESSION_LIST** | no info. |
| **DomainExclusion** | I do know that you can create DE and populate it with the `google.com` domain for example and then you can use it in Advanced Exclusions in Journey Builder and Guided Sends but are there any other places where it can be used? |
| **Event DE Template** | no info. |
| **PushSendLog** | usual SendLog Template for Push Notifications, no questions here. |
| **SendLog** | usual SendLog Template for Emails, no questions here. |
| **SmartCapture - Contacts Template Extension** | default DE for the SmartCapture feature, even though other DE could be populated via SmartCapture, thus the purpose of this template is debatable. |
| **SMSSendLog** | usual SendLog Template for SMS, no questions here. |
| **SMSSubscriptionLog** | reflects the same name as Data View but then I do not understand its purpose. |
| **SMSMessageTracking** | same as the previous point. |
| **SocialPages Default Template Extension** | no info. |
| **TriggeredSendDataExtension** | once you populate this DE, predefined Triggered Send Definition would be triggered to send an email. Are there any nuances or other use-cases? |

Are there any other templates that could be enabled on top of mentioned ones?

Any bits of information would be useful here, thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm working on tracking some of this info down.

Comment: Same, chasing SF Advanced level Support and will update the question once there would be anything clear.

Comment: boring piece of info, but I tested one thing: CONTEXTUAL_SUPPRESSION_LIST is the type that also Auto-Suppression Configurations (ASC) are filed. My expectation was MAYBE it can be used to create my own ASC. However using this template to create a data extension in my test did nothing you'd expect. The resulting data extension does not suppress anything, neither based on email, nor on custom keys. It does also not appear in the Auto Suppression Configuration Menu, and thus can also not be tied to send classifications or sender profile.

Comment: piece of info on TriggeredSendDataExtension: this is the template you need to use to create a DE that holds your data in a Transactional API Journey. No other DEs can be used for this purpose.